# How Does John Carter Know He's From Virginia?

Tags: john-carter, edgar-rice-burroughs

John Carter, in the books, repeatedly states that he has no idea how old he is and can't remember his childhood, yet he also repeatedly and proudly cites that he's from Virginia, or he's referred to as a "Virginian Gentleman."

Now, being a native 6th generation Virginian, I love reading that, but how can he be sure he's from Virginia if he can't remember his childhood, much less his parents or anything about his birth?

Comment: Maybe it's just the last thing of any importance 'to him' that he remembers, or bothers to remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where do you say you're from?

I grew up in New York, but have lived in Florida for the past 16 years. I often tell people that I'm from Florida but grew up in New York.

John Carter lived in Virginia before and I believe after the civil war (if this was changed or detailed further after the first 3 books, I don't know). Saying that he's from Virginia is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's pretty typical of the time frame that he was born in. Not everyone recorded when they were born which is partly why family bibles were so important, they were a record of births and deaths. As far as remembering his childhood I don't recall mine that well either so I don't think that is anything unusual. I know I'm from Georgia though.